# How to solve Javascript Cycle reference?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Fisrt Code

HTML

```
<div>
    <select class="a">
        <option value="1">aaa</option>
        <option value="2">bbb</option>
    </select>
    <input class="b">
</div>
```

A.js

```
const a =  (function initA() {
    const a = document.querySelector('select.a');

    a.addEventListener('change', function() {
        b.setValue(this.value);
    })

    return {
        value: () => a.value
    }
})()

const b =  (function initB() {
    const b = document.querySelector('input.b');

    b.addEventListener('keyup', function (){
        if (this.value.startsWith(a.value()) === false) {
            b.value = a.value();
        }
    })

    return {
        setValue: function (val) {
            b.value = val;
        }
    }
})()
```

An event that initializes the input value with the select value when the select changes, and if the input value does not start with the select value, it initializes with the select value.

I thought it would be used in many places, so I moved the code and modularized it.

Common.js

```
export function initA() {
    const a = document.querySelector('select.a');

    a.addEventListener('change', function() {
        b.setValue(this.value);
    })

    return {
        value: () => a.value
    }
}

export function initB() {
    const b = document.querySelector('input.b');

    b.addEventListener('keyup', function (){
        if (this.value.startsWith(a.value()) === false) {
            b.value = a.value();
        }
    })

    return {
        setValue: function (val) {
            b.value = val;
        }
    }
}
```

A.js

```
const a = initA();
const b = initB();
```

But it occur Uncaught ReferenceError

```
const a = initA(b);
const b = initB(a);
```

The same goes for giving a variable.

how to solve problem?

Comment: `const` does not get [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) the same way as `var` and will throw a **ReferenceError** if read before it is initialized. You could add parameters to `initA` and `initB` to pass the referenced element.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `select` requires an `input` to work properly and the other way around, I would just merge the two functions into one. Both of your functions are not really standalone. Also I prefer passing the elements instead of assuming `select.a` and `input.b`.

```js
function initAB(a, b){
  if(a && b){
    a.addEventListener('change', function(b) {
      b.value = this.value
    }.bind(a, b));
    
    b.addEventListener('keyup', function (a){
      if (this.value.startsWith(a.value) === false) {
        b.value = a.value;
      }
    }.bind(b, a));
    
    return true
  };
  
  return false
};

initAB(
  document.querySelector('select.a'),
  document.querySelector('input.b')
);
```

```html
<div>
    <select class="a">
        <option value="1">aaa</option>
        <option value="2">bbb</option>
    </select>
    <input class="b">
</div>
```